# Alfred unable to remember my preferences and always does reset after re-launch

Tags: macos, permissions, disk, alfred

Alfredapp in mac cannot remember my preferences. All my settings would be reverted to default while I relaunch the app.

I don't have Dropbox Sync in settings and I tried to repair the permission in Disk Utility, but it is still not working.

I found out a way to resolve this issue in https://www.alfredapp.com/help/troubleshooting/preferences/ with the fourth one "4. Create a New User Account" is helpful.

But I think I can't switch to an new account. So is there anyway to resolve this ? What happened to my current account ? Can I repair my account to make everything well ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the following configuration:

> Advanced->Syncing->Set sync folder

Set the folder to your user's directory. Just like **~/backup/alfred3**.

Make sure your Dropbox does not take control of it. Then restart your `alfred`.